# Format of input when doing a new printf in command line in python 3.3

Tags: python, command-line

I am new to python. I just write a server-client program to achieve multiple clients chatting in a room using command line to receive conversation and get input from type. The problem is in the client end. When I am typing, if new words coming from another client, my typing is becoming to be appended. It is like the data I received is appended to what I am typing.

What I used in client reading is:

```
print(myDate)
```

What I used to display new conversation on command line is:

```
myDate = input()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing input and output.

If you are using a multi-threaded client, one thread writing to the `stdout` output will be intermingled with another thread taking input on `stdin` and showing what is being typed with the standard input echo.

Any characters typed for the `input()` call are echoed to `stdout` and that is mixed with anything else being written to `stdout` at the same time.

This does *not* mean that the actual return value of `input()` is going to contain anything other than what the end user typed.

You'll have to build a more sophisticated terminal-based UI to keep `stdout` and input echo separated. Something like [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) could work, but this requires some sophistication.